# Django Routes intercepting api request and serving index page

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a urls.py file with the following routes

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from .core import views
from django.shortcuts import render
from .core.views import index as index_view

def render_react(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'site',views.SiteViewSet,'site')
router.register(r'sitestatus',views.SiteStatusView,'sitestatus')
router.register(r'lender',views.LenderView,'lender')
router.register(r'job',views.JobView,'job')
router.register(r'admin_view',views.AdminUploadView,'admin_view')
router.register(r'site_geography',views.SiteGeographyView,'site_geography')


urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.ObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^.*$', render_react),
    re_path(r"^(?:.*)/?$", render_react),
    # path('',render_react),
]
```

Since serving the static react files via Django with the addition of re_path...xxx it is loading some pages (if supporting data is made with POST requests) but other pages that require api data from the /api route are being intercepted and served the render_react index.html file not the appropriate Api data

I've tried changing the order but I expect that when a request is made to the /api route it correctly calls the api urls and is not served the html.